# Connecting to external SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I developed an application using VS 2012 that needs to be run with an external database. I have a password and a username which had been created where I can login to the portal interface from my desktop and run select queries or access information. Once I tried to connect my VS to their server, it seems the web service is locked down to any connection.

My question is there anyway I can link my application within the VS solution to that database? Appreciate any help/suggestions.

Comment: Absolutely, yes, But your database server must allow remote connections.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Is there a method I can follow to establish the connection remotely?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your connection string for connecting the remote database. Your database server provider will provide you the connection string details.

So, Go ahead and modify your connection string in the project and have fun!

Comment: Sorry, but how do I it?

Comment: What kind of application is it? Are you using a local database for developing your application? A Windows application or a web application. You will have app.config in windows application and web.config file in web application. There you will find the connection string that you need to modify with the connection string that your database provider has given to you.

Comment: It's Web service not local db

Comment: Do you want to consume a web service in your project? Please provide more details in your question so that we can help you.

Comment: I am sorry for not explaining myself well. I want to connect my application through the Web Service! I opened asmx to establish the connection and made a class to call the connection but nothing is working and got errors! :(

Comment: I want to run select queries for tables the reside in Client's server. So thought to connect to database using Web Services

Comment: You can do this without using web service. Just follow my answer and do changes in connection string. If you set up connection string correctly, you can connect to any database. This is the only thing that you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple in your visual studio in view tab open server explorer and click connect to database in this choose sql server authentication and add your username and password in it. Once database is connected Right click the database name and view property it contains connection string replace this connection string with your web.config connection string and then it works fine.

Also review below link
[Connect to SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4yys16a(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My database is not local. However, Can I connect to it through the Web Service? if so How?

Comment: In your webservice project add the following connection string and replace servername,DatabaseName,UserName and password in this.                                             
connetionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=Databasename;
  User ID=UserName;Password=Password"

Comment: It gave me an error as I want to make a connect in the WebService !

Comment: i don't able to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Do you have spare minutes to chat! Could you open the chat and take from there?

Comment: want to connect my application through the Web Service! I opened asmx to establish the connection and made a class to call the connection but nothing is working

Comment: whether you trying to connect with the database via webservice or webapplication it doesn't matter it connect to database via same way. and for asmx service first you need to host asmx service in IIS or your webapplication and then you are able to call that service from your project.

Comment: Is there any tutorial available or any similar work has done for me to see and follow the steps as I am new to web services and establishing connections